# How to install moodle?

Tags: moodle

Im trying to install moodle but it fails all the time

sudo apt install apache2 mysql-client mysql-server php libapache2-mod-php

sudo apt install graphviz aspell ghostscript clamav php-pspell php-curl -y

sudo apt install php-gd php-intl php-xml php-xmlrpc php-ldap php-zip php-soap php-mbstring php-mysql -y

sudo service apache2 restart

entramos en https://download.moodle.org/download.php/stable403/moodle-latest-403.tgz

sudo tar -zxvf Downloads/moodle-latest-403.tgz

sudo mkdir /var/moodledata

sudo chown -R www-data /var/moodledata

sudo chmod -R 777 /var/moodledata

sudo cp -R moodle/ /var/www/html/

sudo chmod -R 0755 /var/www/html/moodle

sudo mysql -u root -p

CREATE DATABASE moodle;
*CAMBIAR moodle POR NOMBRE DE LA BASE DE DATOS

create user 'moodledude'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'passwordformoodledude';
*CAMBIAR moodledude y passwordformoodledude POR USUARIO DE BASE DE DATOS Y POR CONTRASEÑA DE USUARIO DE BASE DE DATOS

GRANT all ON moodle.* TO 'moodledude'@'localhost';
*Cambiar moodle y moodledude por Base de datos y Usuario de base de datos

quit;

sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/moodle

sudo chmod -R 0755 /var/www/html/moodle

Abrimos localhost/moodle en un buscador

Pulsamos Next

Cambiamos Data directory por /var/moodledata

Pulsamos Next

Pulsamos Next

Colocamos los datos de Usuario, Contraseña, Nombre base datos etc...

Pulsamos next

Copiamos desde <?php hasta problems!

sudo nano /var/www/html/moodle/config.php

Pegamos lo copiado

Pulsamos Next

Pulsamos Continue

sudo nano /etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini

Buscamos max_input_vars

Borramos el ; y añadimos un 0

sudo systemctl restart apache2

Pulsamos Reload

Pulsamos continue

Pulsamos continue

Rellenamos las credenciales

Pulsamos Next

Rellenamos los datos de la pagina

Pulsamos Save Changes

Comment: What is the exact error you getting ?

Comment: As above - "Im trying to install moodle but it fails all the time" - why is it failing? What error messages are you getting?